# Trouble: i have a fresh project and hitting view animation shows a video, i didn't even make anything yet!

Tags: rendering

SO basically, i installed blender 2.8 a while ago. I am now trying to create a scene using camera momevements. When I go to the view animation function under the render tab, it shows some video that i tried to edit with blender like 4 months ago. How is this in my fresh project and how the hell do i get it out and never have it repeat again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the old video file (or image sequence) in you temporary folder. On Windows it's in "C:\tmp", on Linux or MacOs it's in "/tmp".